# build failure in android studio:The file name must end with .xml or .png

Tags: android

I encountered a problem. I created a new raw folder in res and used open MP3 files, but it could not play. Before running, Android studio did not report errors, but when running, it said Error: The file name must end with. XML or. png.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one file inside drawable floder named zmr.mp3 Delete that

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a folder named "raw" within folder named "res".
2) Now, put your image file in that "raw" folder.